# Redirect URL path to an action on index?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, redirect

I'm running an apache web server on Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a `domain.com` which directs clients to the `index.html`. On the website there is a button that, when clicked, opens a calendal pop-up widget. I would like people who go to `domain.com/schedule` to land on the index page as if they had clicked that button.

How can I do that simply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need to trigger the pop-up on the client side.
Here's a quick sample you can easily try and adjust (and secure) to your needs:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function isScheduleRequested() {
        if(window.location.href.includes('/schedule')) {
          document.getElementById('button').click();
        }
      }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body onload='isScheduleRequested();'>
      <button type="button" name="button" id="button" onclick="alert('Opening calendar');">Open calendar</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

What this does is, generally speaking, check if the URL of the current page contains the '/schedule' substring' (anywhere, not necessarily at the end, not even only once), and, if it does, then call the button's `click` event.

The `onload='isScheduleRequested();` bit is just to make sure that the javascript script is executed after the body is loaded (and the button element exists).

You can even try this on your computer. Save this code as "index.html" and open it with your browser. Nothing will happen until you click the button. However if you append `?q=/schedule` to the URI, the button's "click" event will be triggered.
(In this example we need to pass the `/schedule` string as part of a GET parameter, since there isn't a domain name, server nor anything fancy set up.).

Comment: This is a great start but it only works for domain.com?q=/schedule whereas I'd like it to work for domain.com/schedule. However when I currently go to domain.com/schedule it correctly says there is no such directory. How can I get that to redirect to my index.html?

Comment: The most simple solution I can think of is defining an alias. Something like `Alias /schedule "/var/www/"`, where `/var/www/` is your current DocumentRoot should work. It basically calls the same directory index, though you should be careful with all your  relative paths.

Comment: Where would I define said alias?

Comment: Either in your _httpd.conf_ or in your virtual host's _conf_ file, preferably before it's corresponding <Directory> section. For example: ``Alias "/schedule" "/var/www"
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>``

Answer (score 0):

At Apache server you can create [rewrite rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) for rendering the same index.html from another path, but displaying the pop-up widget is something you have to solve at application side (eg. JavaScript can use [Web API URL.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) to detect visiting the `domain.com/schedule` URL). When your application detects that user visited `domain.com/schedule` (based on pathname), it can call pop-up widget opening action.